# how do i delete cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie)

How can I delete a cookie using javascript?

Can I have it run whenever my browser start?

Or can I specific what cookie file to delete?