# How to delete a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is my function of creating a cookie correct? How do I delete the cookie at the beginning of my program? is there a simple coding?

```
function createCookie(name,value,days)
```

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,1) {
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" +escape(value);
}

setCookie('cookie_name',mac);

function eraseCookie(c_name) {
  createCookie(cookie_name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: w3schools has good functions for cookies at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp. You can use `setCookie('name', 'value', 0)` to delete a cookie.

Comment: This answer worked for me above all the others: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119715

Answer (score 428):

Try this:

```
function delete_cookie( name, path, domain ) {
  if( get_cookie( name ) ) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+
      ((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
      ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
  }
}
```

You can define `get_cookie()` like this:

```js
function get_cookie(name){
    return document.cookie.split(';').some(c => {
        return c.trim().startsWith(name + '=');
    });
}
```

Comment: how do i set a function that and check what is my cookies and whether it expire yet?

Comment: @Kennedy jason's answer might be useful

Comment: i thought of having a function to view my cookie first.. do you have any coding for that? i want to see it when everytime i visit the webpage, it automatically pop-up an alert for it.

Comment: get_cookie is not defined

Comment: The second version of the function no longer works See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b27Lgxgf/1/. Approach in @Luca 's anwser works

Comment: How is this supposed to work? JavaScript doesn't have built-in `get_cookie()` function.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski I'm pretty sure it was only meant to be a placeholder/reference to an actual function you would define elsewhere.

Comment: It is important to remember when testing the cookie has been deleted that you need to refresh the cookies list to see if the cookie has gone, I had to do this in Chrome debugger.

Comment: I've got a more specific question regarding this, I'll be thankful if you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53196593/3995261

Comment: Is there an advantage to use `expires=...` instead of `Max-Age=0`? And using the Epoch date with `00:00:01` instead of `00:00:00`?

Comment: get_cookie is awkwardly named. Should be has_cookie.

Answer (score 163):

Here a good link on [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```

Comment: note:  in case not working, make sure `path` is correct. see: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies

Comment: domain should be added.

Comment: Also worth noting that both path ***and*** domain need to have correct values.

Comment: Tested, works perfectly even in WKWebView, before page loads. Good job on solution.

Comment: This one didn't work for me in Firefox (I didn't test it elsewhere). Possible because of the location.host missing. The Luca Borrione answer did; `setCookie(name, "", null , null , null, 1);` 

Although the other two functions work well.

Answer (score 58):

would this work?

```
function eraseCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; Max-Age=0'
}
```

I know `Max-Age` causes the cookie to be a session cookie in IE when creating the cookie. Not sure how it works when deleting cookies.

Comment: Set to zero, the cookie will expire when the browser window closes.

Comment: @AyexeM refreshing the windows does the job also

Answer (score 36):

Some of the other solutions might not work if you created the cookie manually.

Here's a quick way to delete a cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'COOKIE_NAME=; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=' + location.host;
```

If this doesn't work, try replacing `location.host` with `location.hostname` in the snippet above.

Comment: This was the answer I chose to use, but in my case did not work until I changed it to `location.hostname`

Comment: This worked for me also with the exception of implementing what @Tom said. Changing location.host to location.hostname

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is the best answer because you don't need complex parsing and selection from all the cookies in document.cookie. The browser will automatically delete the cookie at COOKIE_NAME and leave the rest alone. You can also set a negative value.

Answer (score 19):

Here is an implementation of a [delete cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support) function with unicode support from Mozilla:

```
function removeItem(sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + 
                  "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + 
                  (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + 
                  (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
}

removeItem("cookieName");
```

If you use AngularJs, try [$cookies.remove](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) (underneath it uses a similar [approach](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngCookies/cookieWriter.js)):

```
$cookies.remove('cookieName');
```

Answer (score 18):

You can do this by setting the date of expiry to yesterday.

Setting it to "-1" doesn't work. That marks a cookie as a Sessioncookie.

Comment: your example does not work if you set cookie on another page and try to delete it from a different page. the set works, but cannot delete it.

Comment: I ended up using this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie And you have to delete using path: '/'

Comment: This is a good approach except... just set expiry time to zero. That will cause instant expiration, and not be confusing to anyone ("Why did the developer set expiry time to yesterday? Was that a mistake, did they want a one-day life span?"). Write code so that it makes more sense, and your life will be less confusing down the line. This is an undervalued philosophy in coding nowadays...
Even MDN suggests setting expiry time to zero to delete a cookie.

Answer (score 16):

To delete a cookie I set it again with an empty value and expiring in 1 second.
In details, I always use one of the following flavours (I tend to prefer the second one):

**1.**

```
    function setCookie(key, value, expireDays, expireHours, expireMinutes, expireSeconds) {
        var expireDate = new Date();
        if (expireDays) {
            expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + expireDays);
        }
        if (expireHours) {
            expireDate.setHours(expireDate.getHours() + expireHours);
        }
        if (expireMinutes) {
            expireDate.setMinutes(expireDate.getMinutes() + expireMinutes);
        }
        if (expireSeconds) {
            expireDate.setSeconds(expireDate.getSeconds() + expireSeconds);
        }
        document.cookie = key +"="+ escape(value) +
            ";domain="+ window.location.hostname +
            ";path=/"+
            ";expires="+expireDate.toUTCString();
    }

    function deleteCookie(name) {
        setCookie(name, "", null , null , null, 1);
    }
```

Usage:

```
setCookie("reminder", "buyCoffee", null, null, 20);
deleteCookie("reminder");
```

**2**

```
    function setCookie(params) {
        var name            = params.name,
            value           = params.value,
            expireDays      = params.days,
            expireHours     = params.hours,
            expireMinutes   = params.minutes,
            expireSeconds   = params.seconds;

        var expireDate = new Date();
        if (expireDays) {
            expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + expireDays);
        }
        if (expireHours) {
            expireDate.setHours(expireDate.getHours() + expireHours);
        }
        if (expireMinutes) {
            expireDate.setMinutes(expireDate.getMinutes() + expireMinutes);
        }
        if (expireSeconds) {
            expireDate.setSeconds(expireDate.getSeconds() + expireSeconds);
        }

        document.cookie = name +"="+ escape(value) +
            ";domain="+ window.location.hostname +
            ";path=/"+
            ";expires="+expireDate.toUTCString();
    }

    function deleteCookie(name) {
        setCookie({name: name, value: "", seconds: 1});
    }
```

Usage:

```
setCookie({name: "reminder", value: "buyCoffee", minutes: 20});
deleteCookie("reminder");
```

Answer (score 14):

For people who just want 1 line of code to delete a cookie:

If you created a cookie, for example in a web browser console with `document.cookie = "test=hello"`

You can delete it with:

```
document.cookie = "test=;expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString()
```

Or if you prefer to write the UTC date directly:

```
document.cookie = "test=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
```

If you are on a different path than the cookie (for example if you want to delete a cookie that is used on all paths), you can add `path=/;` after `test=;` and if you are on a different domain (for example when a cookie is set for all subdomains by using `.example.com` instead of `www.example.com`), you can add `domain=.example.com;` after `test=;`.

Update: instead of `expires=...`, using `Max-Age=0` like in other answers works also (tested with Firefox).

Comment: That only works with dev console, unfortunately. Logout.php script doesn't

Answer (score 8):

I had trouble deleting a cookie made via JavaScript and after I added the host it worked (scroll the code below to the right to see the `location.host`). After clearing the cookies on a domain try the following to see the results:

```
if (document.cookie.length==0)
{
 document.cookie = 'name=example; expires='+new Date((new Date()).valueOf()+1000*60*60*24*15)+'; path=/; domain='+location.host;

 if (document.cookie.length==0) {alert('Cookies disabled');}
 else
 {
  document.cookie = 'name=example; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain='+location.host;

  if (document.cookie.length==0) {alert('Created AND deleted cookie successfully.');}
  else {alert('document.cookies.length = '+document.cookies.length);}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this on my websites that works on Chrome and Firefox.

```
function delete_cookie(name) { document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/;  Domain=' + location.host +  '; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; SameSite=None; Secure' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ("JSESSIONID".equals(cookie.getName()) || "LtpaToken2".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                cookie.setValue("");
                cookie.setPath("/");
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
                response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to generate  the cookie from backend and redirect to frontend. The only way I got it working has been to set the expires date in the past in the  backned and redirect back on frontend

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the ability to delete cookies in JavaScript, so to delete it we need to create another cookie with an earlier date.

> Set Cookie

```
let expires = null
const cookieName = 'userlogin'
const d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + value+ ";" + expires + ";path=/";
```

> Delete Cookie

```
let expires = null
const d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = 'userlogin' + "=" + value+ ";" + expires + ";path=/";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to erase every single cookie at once, define the `eraseCookies` function like this:

```js
function eraseCookies() {
    cookies = document.cookie.split("; ").map((a) => a.split("=")[0]) // Get the cookie names
    for (var i in cookies) {
        document.cookie = cookies[i] + "=;expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString() // Erase each cookie
    }
}
```

Then you can erase all cookies by calling `eraseCookies` with no arguments.

[Credits to this answer for how to erase a single cookie.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68443095/15121749)

Answer (score 0):

delete by:

```
document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=' + location.hostname+";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
```

Use location.hostname instead of location.host because location.host also returns a port when it's specified

name is the cookie name