# Delete cookie by name?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I delete a specific cookie with the name `roundcube_sessauth`?

Shouldn't the following:

```
function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = 'roundcube_sessauth' + 
    '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

And then:

```
<a href="javascript:del_cookie(name);">KILL</a>
```

Kill the `roundcube_sessauth` cookie?

Comment: `name`? What's the point of that? Or is it a hangover from a more versatile version that allows you to specify the cookie name?

Comment: Don't think that's a dupe. It specifically asks about clearing _all_ cookies.

Comment: I don't want to delete all cookies... Just one. I found the basic code from googling around. And of course I tried it. @Paxdiablo I assumed it for naming the cookie, but I might be completely wrong.

Comment: @paxdiablo - `How can I delete a ` **`specific`** `cookie`...

Comment: @Derek et al, you seem to misunderstand. I was stating that the proposed dupe from Gabe wasn't a dupe at all because the proposed dupe asked about deleting _all_ cookies and this question asks about deleting a _specific_ cookie. I was _not_ complaining about this question in any way, shape or form :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo - Oh, didn't read the whole thing... Sorry!

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript - delete cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie)

Answer (score 357, accepted):

You should define the path on which the cookie exists to ensure that you are deleting the correct cookie.

```
function set_cookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name +'='+ value +'; Path=/;';
}
function delete_cookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

If you don't specify the path, the browser will set a cookie relative to the page you are currently on, so if you delete the cookie while on a different page, the other cookie continues its existence.

*Edit based on @Evan Morrison's comment.*
Be aware that in some cases to identify the correct cookie, the `Domain` parameter is required.
Usually it's defined as `Domain=.yourdomain.example`.
Placing a *dot* in front of your domain name means that this cookie may exist on any sub-domain (`www` also counts as sub-domain).

Also, as mentioned in @RobertT's answer, `HttpOnly` cookies cannot be deleted with JavaScript on the client side.

Comment: This was driving me nuts! After I added Path=/, I was able to delete. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it doesn't work without `Path` in most cases.

Comment: I wasn't able to delete a cookie until I added both path and the correct 'Domain=value; '   ... So my statement was: document.cookie = "cookieName= ; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=.myDomain.com"

Comment: This solution still works, but can be written slightly more concisely with `Max-Age=0`, if you care about such things.

Answer (score 201):

In order to delete a cookie set the `expires` date to something in the past.  A function that does this would be.

```
var delete_cookie = function(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
```

Then to delete a cookie named `roundcube_sessauth` just do.

```
delete_cookie('roundcube_sessauth');
```

Comment: I feel like this *should* be working (it looks like it should work :D!), but I'm viewing the cookies set by my page in firefox and when I click the "KILL" button, the cookie isn't getting deleted. Any idea why?

Comment: This works in Google Chrome.  Install firebug and see if there are any errors.

Comment: No errors, I guess it's just not deleting the cookie in Roundcube. It probably deletes other cookies just fine.

Comment: For users looking for an answer to this question, please see the answer below. The `path=/` key is important for browser compatibility.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me on Chrome, haven't tried it in Firefox. But emii's answer below did work.

Comment: This does work, but if the cookie specifies domain or path, you should also set them in the expired cookie.

Comment: The javascript is not standard at all

Comment: @CoppolaEmilio, it's not a javascript problem, it's a browser problem.

Comment: This doesn't work, you need to pass the exact domain

Answer (score 11):

//if passed exMins=0 it will delete as soon as it creates it.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exMins) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exMins*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();  
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

setCookie('cookieNameToDelete','',0) // this will delete the cookie.
```

Comment: exMins is undefined in this example, you probably meant exdays

Comment: Yeah.. instead rename argument exdays to exMins.. thanks #BhBh

Answer (score 10):

I'm not really sure if that was the situation with Roundcube version from May '12, but for current one the answer is that you can't delete `roundcube_sessauth` cookie from JavaScript, as it is marked as `HttpOnly`. And this means it's not accessible from JS client side code and can be removed only by server side script or by direct user action (via some browser mechanics like integrated debugger or some plugin).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime());
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = 'COOKIE_NAME' + "=" + "" + ";domain=domain.example;path=/;" + expires;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleteCookieByName(name) {
    let newCookie = document.cookie.replace(new RegExp(`${name}=[^ ]*( )?`), '');
    document.__defineGetter__("cookie", function() {return newCookie} );
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth mention that a `HttpOnly` is not accessible from javascript client side code.

You can, however, call a `"/delete"` route from your server. The route will send a new cookie with `expires` = "some date in the past", overwriting/deleting the previous cookie!

Here is a server route example using the "Express" framework for a HTTP DELETE request:

```js
const express = require("express")
const routes = express.Router()
routes.delete("/delete-cookie", (req, res) => {
res
  .status(200)  //OK
  .clearCookie("name-of-your-cookie")
  .send("Cookie deleted from user's browser")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used blow code for different environment.

```js
  document.cookie = name +`=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;Domain=.${document.domain.split('.').splice(1).join('.')}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

for Cookies you can refer this [cookie documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

for setting the cookies with domain in js:

```
 function setCrossSubdomainCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, minutes) {
  const assign = `${name}=${escape(value)};`
  const d = new Date()
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + minutes * 60 * 1000)
  const expires = `expires=${d.toUTCString()};`
  const path = "path=/;"
  const domain = "domain=.domainName.example;"
  document.cookie = assign + expires + path + domain
}
```

For deleting the cookies with domain in js:

```
export async function deleteCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = `${name}=; path=/; domain=.edyst.com; expires=${new Date(
    0
  ).toUTCString()}`
}
```

Note: we cannot store cookies without expiry time but domain is optional can be excluded and if want to store cookie for long or don't want your cookie to expire then use this while setting the cookie

```
 const expires = "expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT"
```