# delete or clear cookie using javascript or php

Tags: php, javascript

I want to javascript or php script delete the cookie that i was set up with javascript now i want to delete that cookie.

here this is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.hash;
    var result = url.split('?');
    var advertise = result[1].split("&");
    var id = advertise[0].split("=");
    document.cookie = "update_id=" + id[1];
    var name = advertise[1].split("=");
    document.cookie = "update_name=" + name[1];
</script>
```

how to delete or clear this cookie using javascript or php code.

Comment: set its date to back date it will be deleted automatically.

Comment: `document.cookie = 'update_name=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';` check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10593045/921204

Comment: this cookie stored to update data in database , after updated i want to delete this cookie immediately.so next time i will get new cookie.

Comment: after clicked submit button i want delete it immediately..if not yet delete it , it will get the old cookie name . so it will duplicate data when i save it into my database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in JavaScript :

Just call `delete_cookie` function by passing your cookie name.

```
function delete_cookie(cookie_name)
{
  var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // current date & time
  cookie_date.setTime (cookie_date.getTime() - 1);
  document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
}
```

You can do like this in PHP :

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "", time()-3600);
```