# How to delete __utma cookie from chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, cookies, google-analytics

I am trying to delete the Google analytic cookies from website. I am using this code to delete the cookies, But the Google analytic cookies is not remove fro the Google Chrome.  How to delete the  Google analytic cookies from Google Chrome ?.

```
function clearCookie(name, domain, path){
    try {
        function Get_Cookie( check_name ) {
                // first we'll split this cookie up into name/value pairs
                // note: document.cookie only returns name=value, not the other components
                var a_all_cookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
                    a_temp_cookie = '',
                    cookie_name = '',
                    cookie_value = '',
                    b_cookie_found = false;

                for ( i = 0; i < a_all_cookies.length; i++ ) {
                    // now we'll split apart each name=value pair
                    a_temp_cookie = a_all_cookies[i].split( '=' );

                    // and trim left/right whitespace while we're at it
                    cookie_name = a_temp_cookie[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

                    // if the extracted name matches passed check_name
                    if ( cookie_name == check_name ) {
                        b_cookie_found = true;
                        // we need to handle case where cookie has no value but exists (no = sign, that is):
                        if ( a_temp_cookie.length > 1 ) {
                            cookie_value = unescape( a_temp_cookie[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') );
                        }
                        // note that in cases where cookie is initialized but no value, null is returned
                        return cookie_value;
                        break;
                    }
                    a_temp_cookie = null;
                    cookie_name = '';
                }
                if ( !b_cookie_found ) {
                  return null;
                }
            }
            if (Get_Cookie(name)) {
                var domain = domain || document.domain;
                var path = path || "/";
                document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + new Date + "; domain=" + domain + "; path=" + path;
            }
    }
    catch(err) {}    
};

clearCookie('__utmz','.domain','/');
clearCookie('__utmb','.domain','/');
clearCookie('__utmc','.domain','/');
clearCookie('__utma','.domain','/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Following statement -

```
 document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + new Date + "; domain=" + domain + "; path=" + path;
```

it will make the cookie as session cookie. For deleting cookie, you should set past time. check this -

[Delete cookie by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name)

However, there would be one problem. Since these are google analytics cookies, so if google analytics is still enabled and working, it will set the cookies again. If you do not want to set the cookies again by google analytics, then you need to disable google analytics firstly

Comment: Thanks for your great support.Can u give a solution for disable analytics.

Comment: if you are using ga.js then this code would disable google analytics -       window['ga-disable-UA-XXXXXX-Y'] = true;

Comment: One chrome extension I used added GA on all sites. Apparently there are a few extensions that do that in order to track users everywhere. If anyone sees strange GA cookies, I suggest checking the extensions.