# How to delete cookies from browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have need to delete  the cookies from the browser . I can do it manually by going to the cookies and by deleting it . How can i do it programmatically ?

[image: deleting cookies from browser]

Comment: Have you tried [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you wanting to delete all cookies or just cookies previously created by your site?

Comment: If you are doing lots of cookie manipulation then something like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) will make your life a lot easier

Comment: I am trying to delete all the cookies by https://login.microsoftonline.com/ ...But even deleting all the cookies will do my job for now .

Comment: @Adam I have tried if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}  and               string[] cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
            foreach (string cookie in cookies)
            {
                Response.Cookies[cookie].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies[cookie].Value = "";
            }

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your .Net Application by first removing it and then adding it with passed expiration. Try using the following code:

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("UserSettings");
   HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
   myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
   myCookie.Value = null;
   HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(myCookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you can't access to third party cookies. I mean that you can't modify or delete cookies created by other domains different than yours.

I hope this helps

Comment: Can i write a code that will delete these cookies from the browser ?

Comment: Not from Javascript, but externally, cookies are usually saved to a folder, depending on the browser and operating system. You in some cases you could write an external program or script to perform that task if you have enough permissions.