# Unable to Delete/Overwrite existing cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to delete a cookie that is set by Magento.

The Cookie set via Magento on the domain is

```
Name: PHPSESSID
Content: [random string]
Domain: .bgl-...l.co.uk
Path: /
Send For: Any type of connection
Expires: 60 minutes
```

I have a page in a sub folder `bgl-...l.co.uk/hq-admin` with a link that links to another page. I also have an onClick function for this to delete the cookie however ti doesn't seem to work.

Current Code:

```
<a onclick="delete_cookie();" href="http://bgl-...l.co.uk/" target="_blank">Log in</a>
<script>
function delete_cookie() {
  document.cookie = "PHPSESSID=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/; domain=bgl-opal.co.uk;";
}
</script>
```

Currently the page just refreshes and the cookie remains intact. The cookie is unaffected if I run the JS directly in my browser console too.

Comment: Maybe when you link to the page it sets the cookie again.

Comment: Try putting a `.` in `domain=.bgl-opal.co.uk` to match the actual cookie.

Comment: I have tried removing the link and changing the 'a' to be a 'button' instead and it doesn't seem to fire or do anything.

Comment: Changed it to document.cookie = "PHPSESSID=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/; domain=.bgl-...l.co.uk;"; and it still doesn't do anything

Comment: Or just leave out the `path` and `domain` parameters.

Comment: What you're doing should work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name

Comment: Can't leave out the parameters as the cookie name is generic and I do not want to impact on other cookies. I only want to remove the one for this domain

Comment: Cookie operations only affect the one that's being used for the current page.

Comment: Current page or domain? so if a cookie is set by /index.php/customer/account/login I cannot modify this from /hq-admin ?

Comment: The only cookie that's visible is the one with the most specific domain and path that includes the current page. If the cookie has path=/, it can be set and deleted from both pages. If that page sets a cookie with path=/index.php/customer/account then it won't be visible at all to /hq-admin, and it can't delete it.

Comment: The basic point is that when you delete the cookie, you'll delete whichever cookie is in force for the current page.

Comment: Okay so the cookie has a path of / so it should be able to be deleted. I'm now just wondering if this is a firefox issue

Comment: What's the chance that one of the most popular browsers has such a serious bug in a common operation like this?

Comment: I know, clutching at straws now! Just checking to see if magento sets the cookie has httpOnly