# On click event not deleting browser cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I want to delete browser cookie when a button clicked. I have checked my code and found that `onclick` event working and execute the `deleteCookie` function but cookie not deleted.

Below is my code:

```
$(".close-conversation").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('button clicked'); 
      deleteCookie('instanceId');
      deleteCookie('chatWindow');
      deleteCookie('userdataLoaded');
 });


//deleteCookie function

function deleteCookie(cname) {
   document.cookie = cname + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
   console.log('cookie deleted')
 }
```

please help me to find the mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try setting the path too ? `document.cookie = cname + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";`

Comment: Your code is working perfectly, check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ku3zgLqe/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete cookie by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

You have hard coded expires value, set it to current time to delete cookie at the moment.

```
function deleteCookie(cname) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime());
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString(); 
    document.cookie = cname + '=;'+ expires;
    console.log('cookie deleted')
}
```