# Unable to delete (set to expire) cookies on localhost

Tags: javascript, cookies, localhost

I'm using the following functions to create and delete cookies.  This has worked great in the past, but recently I started debugging via localhost and I have noticed the `deleteCookie` function is no longer working.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exsecs) {
    let expires = "";
    if (exsecs) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exsecs * 1000));
        expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    } else {
        expires = "expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT"
    }
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function deleteCookie( name ) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty straight forward.  Is there a better way to "delete" cookies that works locally? Or is there some configuration change I can make?

Comment: Something very similar -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995984/1745073

Comment: Looks like that works.  But since that wasn't the specific question over there (localhost is never mentioned), I think this should probably stay open. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving this as a possible answer until a more solid answer with relavent explanation comes by:

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

Specifying the Path attribute seems to work for other's who faced similar problems.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995984/1745073) (although there is no mention of it being specific to localhost)