# Disabling third party cookies as per GDPR compliance

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am currently working on developing a solution for clients to comply with incoming GDPR regulations. Part of this task involves allowing users to explicitly opt-in and opt-out of cookies. I am using [Cookie Consent](https://cookieconsent.insites.com) for the general framework of displaying notices and allowing users to opt in/out but when it comes to actually developing code to implement that, I am stuck.

Google Analytics explicitly provides an opt-out function in the form of:

```
window[ga-disable-UA-XXXXXXXX-Y] = true;
```

However I have not been able to find ways to do this for other third-party cookies, such as Twitter and LinkedIn despite much googling. Twitter, for example, doesn't seem to offer anything similar to Google Analytics in the form of opt-out code; it seems like users need to log into their Twitter account and change settings through that, but on the sites I am working on Twitter is setting cookies because Twitter embeds are used on the site regardless of whether a visitor has an account or not.

The closest I have came to a solution is a suggestion to [delete cookies by setting their expiry date in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name). However, AFAIK this won't stop cookies being set again. Also how then do I explicitly re-allow these cookies if the user decides to opt-in to allowing cookies in the future?

Comment: Is there a reason for the GDPR tag being removed? I believe it to be relevant because it defines the functionality that is needed from my question

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366486/burninate-gdpr

Comment: Thanks for responding @VadimKotov , I have removed the tag again.

Comment: @Roy, did you ever solve this?  I've had to pretty much remove everything from my website (embedded YouTube, social sharing etc..) until I can get some kind of solution.  Tried various 'cookie banner' solutions that seems to be floating around, but none of them seem to stop these 3P cookies...

Comment: @Zippy Sadly not, so far as I've been able to find there doesn't seem to be a satisfactory complete solution to this problem as of yet