# How to remove cookie from header in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs framework,I used cookie for user login and now at logout time i want to delete/remove cookie,How can i do this ? here is my code for add cookie

Cookies.set('email', email )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete cookie by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name)

Comment: @DanPhilipBejoy no i am working with Nextjs

Comment: guess this work should be done right before calling the api. How do you call the apis? there should be kinda option for manipulating it.
Seems not highly related to the React.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the package [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie)

To remove the cookie while logging out call `Cookies.remove('email')` at the end of the handler function.

If the log out call returns a positive response for successful logout, then maybe use that as a condition for removing the cookie.

Comment: Its working, I am new in Reactjs so i want to know that is this good approach to save login details in cookes (use cooke in login module)

Comment: Saving token (not the login details) is quite standard.

Comment: you mean something like jwt token ? and second question is ...is this cookie method is correct ?

Comment: Yes. Cookie method is fine.

Comment: and should we use jwt token or something other ?

Comment: JWT token is quite standard too.