# Delete Cookies on Blazor Server

Tags: cookies, blazor, blazor-server-side

Can you show me how to remove the password that Google Chrome has saved?

I have designed a login form.

There are 2 Textboxes (account and password).

I see Google Chrome has saved the password and account for the next login.

→ Now I want to delete it when I log out.

I am new to Blazor Server, so can you guide me in detail how to do it.

I looked at this Link, but I don't know how to apply it.
[delete-cookie-by-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593013/delete-cookie-by-name)

Thank you.