# javascript jquery mass delete cookies have similar name?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm looking for way to remove all my web cookies which have similar name "SID12345UID123456789" , all have SID and UID in their name ..

it can be done by jquery or pure JavaScript
thanks for any advices

**Update: worked**
base on other script i made this one it work but simple with indexOf .. i know some one can do better by regex match ..
please help

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    var equals = cookies[i].indexOf("="),
        name = equals > -1 ? cookies[i].substr(0, equals) : cookies[i];

    if ( name.indexOf('SID') > 0 && name.indexOf('UID') > 0 ){
        alert(name);//for test
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating these in your own code, you should delete the existing one before creating the new one (thus avoiding the problem).

Otherwise you can use a function like one found on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie). Run a loop that looks for a cookie with that name. If it finds it, delete it and then look again (until there are none left).

Comment: i'm just new bie in javascript ... i have create small code here could you have look .. http://jsfiddle.net/SLcnz/  i'm still can not make it work..

Comment: Fantastic!  If you're happy to tick my answer and/or add +1, I'd appreciate it :)