# jQuery - delete cookie

Tags: jquery

How Can I delete cookie contains string

> displayName

in name?
it is only one cookie with this string, but I don't know all name, only the part?

Comment: I think you cannot do this. If you can create a cookie name dynamically so you can set the cookie's value to null with jquery: `$.cookie("_constantStringName_" + variable, null);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the full name of the cookie, you could easily find out by inspecting the entire cookie collection:

```
var names = document.cookie.split(';')
   .map(function(c) { return c.split('=')[0]; })
   .filter(function(c) { return c.indexOf('displayName') > -1; });
```

Here, `names` would contain all the cookies with `displayName` in their name. If you're sure that'll only ever be one, go ahead and delete `names[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (i = 0; i <= cookies.length; i++) {
    if (cookies[i].indexOf(name) != -1)
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/";
}
```

This deletes all cookies that have the content of `name` in their name. This is pure Javascript, no JQuery involved.

The reason why I set the date to `01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT` is, because we already passed that date and so, the browser will delete the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

delete cookie:

```
function Delete_Cookie( name, path, domain ) 
{
   if ( Get_Cookie( name ) )
   document.cookie=name+"="+((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
                                   ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}
```

or

```
function del_cookie(name)
{
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

source: [javascript - delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie)