# Disable PHP Sessions for a URL Path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, session

I want sessions working on this path:

```
domain.com/sessions
```

and I want them turned off for this path:

```
domain.com/sessions-off
```

Any idea on how I can do this? Once you've called session_start(), how do you make it so the server won't output a session cookie?

Answer (score 2):

In apache you can try setting:

```
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

In the .htaccess file under domain.com/sessions-off

Answer (score 1):

Once you've set a cookie, it's the browser that sends it on each request, not the server. If you don't like the cookies being sent, the traditional way to deal with that is to have a new subdomain, as the cookie is scoped to the subdomain it was set on. If you just want $_SESSION to be blank, don't call session_start().

Answer (score 0):

1) if you store session data on server side, 
then you can use `session_destroy()` on the beginning of your page.

2) if you use cookies on client side, you need to do that via js

you can look here for details : [javascript - delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie)