# Destroy session variable when JS function being called

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have made a function `destroy()` that is being called `onclick` event of `logout` button. But the problem is server side code in that function being always called on page load whether the logout button being clicked or not. All i want to do is to set a value for session varaible `lastVisit` `onclick` event of `logout` button. Kindly let me know what is an appropriate way to do it thanks,

```
              function destroy()
                {
                <?php $_SESSION['lastVisit'] = "logout"; ?>
                alert('hi');

                }
```

Comment: PHP is executed server-side, _JavaScript_ is executed client side, when a page is generated, it's server side, when a page is viewed (and _JavaScript_ run), it's client side.

Comment: i think you need cookies

Comment: you cant mix php with javascript like that

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks for clearing my confusion, kindly let me know how can i set a value for session varaible lastVisit onclick event of logout button

Comment: @paka hmm i can use cookies. So how to destroy the cookie named `lastVisit`

Comment: @user2304394 try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie

Comment: @paka thanks for the heads up i solved it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing php code with javascript code they dont work together like that you will need to do an ajax call and this is made easy since you are using jQuery.

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#LogoutButtonID").click(destroy());
});
function destroy() {
   jQuery.ajax({
      "url":"http://www.example.com/someScriptToLogout.php",
      "success":function() {
         alert("i logged out");
      }
   });
}
```

and in someScriptToLogout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['lastVisit'] = "logout";
```

Comment: Don' forget `session_start()` :)

Comment: @moonwave99, oh yes i did seem to forget that didnt i :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not go the Ajax way?

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['endSession'])){
destroy();

echo 'Hi';
}

function destroy(){
  $_SESSION['lastVisit'] = "logout"; 
                }
```

javascript:

```
$.post('logOut.php',{endSession:'yes'},function(hi){

alert(hi)

})
```

That for sure will do what you want

**Please note:** This solution will assume that you have jQuery in your page and that your php codes are in a page named `logOut.php`