# How to delete cookies in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I apply this method in ci4 to delete_cookie but it can't work.

```
if(delete_cookie(get_cookie("urs_name"))){
            echo "coookie deleted";
        }else{
            echo "Unable to delete cookies";
        }
```

Anyone can help one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686155/remove-a-cookie

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete cookie on codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565336/how-to-delete-cookie-on-codeigniter)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
delete_cookie('name', $domain, $path);
```

[see this link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html?highlight=delete_cookie#delete_cookie)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to delete a cookie in PHP.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['urs_name'])){
    echo "coookie deleted";
    setcookie ”urs_name”, "", time() - 3600);
}else{
    echo "Unable to delete cookies";
}
?>
```

**I wrote this on Aug 8 I just edited code Aug 9 realizing you are using
codeigniter-4 you can use PHP to do the same thing just replaced by code with your coat.**

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do like that

```
helper('cookie');
delete_cookie('cookiename')
```