# Removing a cookie and abandoning a session does not remove the cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms, httpcookie

I created a cookie in my C# WebForms application, which I am testing on IE10 on Windows 7 64-bit.

The problem is that I cannot delete the cookie from the code behind. If I refresh the page or simply click on a hyperlink to goes back to the exact same page, the page can still read the cookie.

I have a popup control that in response to the user pressing the ok button, will do:

```
String key = "mycookiedata";
HttpCookie oCookie = null;
if (null != HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key])
{
    oCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];

    oCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(oCookie);
}

Session.Remove(key);
Session.Abandon();
Session.Clear();
```

The code behind completes, and control goes back to the user. All seems fine until I refresh the page and find out that the cookie that I thought got deleted was not. I also tried out of sheer curiosity to close the browser window and reload the page in a new browser, and the cookie was still there. A user who logs out, should feel comfortable that they truly logged out and the cookie is gone.

Did I miss something in the code?

Comment: You should use Fiddler and inspect request / response. It might be that while the cookie is deleted on the response, it could be re-created on the postback (GET).  

Also, are you doing a full postback or just an AJAX update ?

Comment: cahmadzadeh, I do not know the answer to your question. The okay button processing is in response to a DevExpress callback panel method call, cpdialog.PerformCallback(). That does do a post back, but I do not know the type. I suspect Ajax update. I do not think that I ever heard of Fiddler, so I will definitely check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I thought that I saw a comment but cannot find it about my Session call being Request and not Response. That might be. I tried adding that as a thought to get rid of the cookie. That did not work. It was worth a try. I will investigate the recreation of the cookie. Sadly, I cannot really use the debugger in Visual Studio, because the cookie works on the domain and not the local entity, but I can get flow from Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, you have to do a FULL postback (the page has to reload) otherwise the cookie won't be actually set (and therefore, it will not expire and won't be deleted).

Comment: cahmadzadeh, I will have to contact DevExpress and find out if I get a full postback or not. On another front, I removed my temporary Session calls, as it did not do anything.

Comment: You do not need to contact them, just look at the page, when you click the button. Does it reloads entirely (= full postback) or not (=ajax postback or partial update or asyncpostback)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> You cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer.
> ```
>
> However, you can direct the user's browser to delete the cookie by
>   setting the cookie's expiration date to a past date.
>
> The next time a user makes a request to a page within the domain or
>   path that     set the cookie, the browser will determine that the
>   cookie has expired and remove it.

Check this **[Delete a Cookie from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)**

All you can do is you can make the cookie to be expired, by setting the past time

The below code will do that

```
if (Request.Cookies[key] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(key);
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: @cahmadzadeh, `You cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer` for this statement I have given reference and what ever she does is correct.

Comment: As Cahmadzadeh said, I did do remove the cookie the proper way. The session calls was merely a thought added now about a half hour ago and summarily removed. That said, the second sentence in the link that Murali gave seems interesting. I wonder what would qualify as a "request". Here is that sentence, "The next time a user makes a request to a page within the domain or path that set the cookie, the browser will determine that the cookie has expired and remove it."

Comment: @SarahWeinberger, Thanks for indicating that sentence. I added with my answer

Comment: The page does NOT reload. Cahmadzadeh asked if it does or not. The cancel has the AutoPostBack="False", but I removed that attribute, default being true, from the ok button, yet still no post back.

Comment: Adding a PerformPostBack() call after the logout dialog closes, which then in turn performs a Response.Redirect("/", false); call, does not work. I am still logged in. Upsetting.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting a page, as in the first answer did not work. I tried several variants and nada.

I finally thought out the answer. In my EndCallback JavaScript event for the DevExpress callback panel for the ok button on the logout dialog, I implemented a call to a JavaScript function, Delete_Cookie. Having JavaScript delete the cookie worked!

There were two changes from the code behind, either one or both could have been what did the trick.

1. Delete the cookie from the client and not the C# code behind.
2. The Delete_Cookie code set the expire date not to the current date less one (1), but rather a date in 1970. I suspect the 1970 date did the trick.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie) to the article, whose Delete_Cookie code I used.

Comment: Be careful though, if this cookie must be deleted for security purposes, doing it client side is a huge vulnerability (as JavaScript code can be disabled easily).