# how to delete cookies on app engine app in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session-cookies

How to delete cookies on app engine app using GWT in Java every time user close the browser of the app? So that it won't remember the previous user when the user open the app again in his browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an App Engine session for authentication, you simply need to kill it:

```
session.invalidate();
```

If you store a cookie on the client, your app needs to take care of it - there is nothing special about App Engine here:

[javascript - delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie)