# Deleting Cookies with same name across different domains using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

url with the issue
https://www.one.om/testtranslate

trying to delete all cookies named 
"googtrans"

when you select a language from the google translate dropdown, the page translates as expected, refresh the page to see the issue:

now there should be two cookies with the name "googtrans", but different domains:

```
domain 1: ".one.om"
domain 2: "www.one.om"
```

when i use

```
$.cookie('googtrans',null, {domain:'www.one.om'});
```

that works fine, but

```
$.cookie('googtrans',null, {domain:'.one.om'});
```

does not
any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because you are basically trying to change the main domain's cookie from a sub-domain.

Comment: just tried it on https:// www.one.om


and still no success

Comment: If you go to *one.om* you will be redirected to *www.one.om* before the script can run. Your domain has to be without the *www*

Comment: story of my life with this site! so im assuming that modifying main domain cookies from subdomains is the source of the issue here

Comment: Yes, for security reasons the browser does not allow that. *www* is a sub-domain of *.one.com* but *.one.com* can delete any cookies from the sub-domains because it's the main domain name. I think there is a problem with the google script because of the domain redirection from without *www.* to *www.* and the cookie is set for both domains.

Comment: ah i see your point... i will consider this resolved then. thanks spokey, i await your official answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I think I managed to get it working. I might not get it correctly, but according to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work)
it should be possible.

Please try and use the code below, it worked for me on Chromium (I modified the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2138471/4125391)):

```
function createCookie(name, value, days, domain) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; domain=" + domain + "; path=/";
}

function eraseCookie(name, domain) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1, domain);
}
```

and then call:

```
eraseCookie("googtrans", ".one.om"); //erases the .one.om domain cookie
eraseCookie("googtrans", ""); //erases the www.one.om domain cookie
```

Please let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: can i have your babies?! sorry, i know we're not supposed to have a question within a question! this worked for me on chrome for mac... gonna give it a go on the other browsers. thanks! :)

Comment: I will not give you my babies Craig ;) Great news though, glad that it worked!