# How do I delete the cookies after signout of a User

Tags: angularjs, cookies

In my app I have local sign-in and Google+ sign-in. Suppose if I login with the Google+ and after I click on the signout it works perfectly. But afterwards, if I need to login with a new User it is directly logging in with previous login without asking for login. For this reason I want to delete my cookies.

The corresponding code is given below...

this is my HTML file:

```
<a ng-click="signout()">Signout</a>
```

Controller.js:

```
$scope.signout = function () {
       $http.get('/auth/signout').success(function(response){           
        console.log("nothing" + JSON.stringify(response));               
           var wind = window.user;               
           $cookies.wind = '';               
           console.log("windows" + JSON.stringify(wind));              
           $cookieStore.remove('wind');            
          //delete $cookies["wind"];           
        $location.path('/');

       });
    };
```

Where window.user is where the cookie data will be storing.

server.js:

```
exports.signout = function (req, res) {

    req.logout();    
    res.status(200).send("logged out");    
//     res.redirect('/');     
    console.log('server side signout function called');
};
```

I tried $cookieStore.remove('wind'); and delete $cookies["wind"];
But both are not working, Please tell me of other methods to solve this (and any solutions to this problem)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie

Answer (score 0):

This question is more networking question likely. You can't delete cookies. What you can do is only set the expired date of cookies to past.

```
document.cookie = mycookiename + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

Then, browser will detect either the cookies is validate or not by checking expired date.

---

**Important**

So far, version 1.3.6, there is no way to settings cookies expired date with `ngCookies` prepared by AngularJS. I will recommend you to using open source instead of using `ngCookies`. Here's the one I am using.

https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie

Comment: May i know what is "mycookiename" there? i don't understand that, because i am new to cookies. could you help in that