# Delete cookies javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a cookie

```
console.log(document.cookie);
Clickme=a-6,a-7,a-8,a-9,a-10,a-17,a-8,
```

I want to delete this cookie, I have tried following things but they aren't working

```
document.cookie = "Clickme=; max-age = -1;"
document.cookie =  Clickme+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;"
document.cookie = "Clickme=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - delete cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie)

Comment: the second attempt should've worked - if it were correct javascript (so close) `document.cookie =  "Clickme=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT"` - third attempt should've worked too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following to remove a cookie.

```js
function deleteCookie(name) {
  var domain = location.hostname,
      path = '/'; // root path

  document.cookie = [
    name, '=',
    '; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString(),
    '; path=' + path,
    '; domain=' + domain
  ].join('');
}

deleteCookie('Clickme');
```

Using an array helps me see the parts separately, and using `Date(0).toUTCString()` guarantees I've got the correct date.

Comment: This does require that the cookie path was set to the root. In hindsight it might have been better to pass path and domain through as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
    function delete_cookie( name ) {
     document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
     }

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Delete cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie)

You can use this function

```
function removeItem(sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + 
                  "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + 
                  (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + 
                  (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
}

removeItem("cookieName");
```

In angular you can use `$cookies.remove` as well, if that helps.