# How to remove cookies in jQuery with a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to remove some Cookies in a jQuery click function.

**In HTML:**

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="search-this-day">Search</a>
```

**In jQuery:**

```
$('#search-this-day').on('click', function () {
   Cookie("fromDate",null,-1);
   // or
   deleteCookie("fromDate");
   // or
   $.cookies.del('fromDate');
});
```

But none have worked !

Where is my problem?

Comment: $.removeCookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' });
Try this

Comment: Hi @NedimHozić Don't work this code!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [this plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which is very helpfull for cookies managing !

Other way you should put the expire date to `null` like this :

```
$.cookie("name", null, { path: '/' });
```

Take care you have an `'s'` in your code : `$.cookieS.del(..`

Comment: Hi, Dont work this code !!!

Comment: What's your error ? What happen ? Did you tried this answers  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie ?

Comment: Do not give an error, 
Cookies can not be deleted.