# cookie is not deleted inIE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I have created cookie in js 'login_time' it is deleted in 'Alt+CTRL+DEL' in chrome and firefox but not deleted in IE.I have checked 'Cookies and website data' and 'temporary Internet files and website files' but still cookie is alive after delete in IE.

```js
if ((document.cookie.indexOf('login_time=') < 0)) { //check cookie not exist
  var expiry = new Date();
  expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  document.cookie = 'login_time=yes; expires=' + expiry;
  alert('cookie not exist and so created');
} else {
  alert('cookie already exist exist');
}
```

Comment: The code you posted creates the cookie, it doesn't delete it.

Comment: Why do you think Ctl-Alt-Del should delete the cookie?

Comment: for developing purpose need to clear cookie and create again

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie?rq=1