# Javascript can't expire cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm working on some stuff with javascript and working with cookies, which, from the code it can be edited and read, but they can't set expire date and deleted. For some reason, setting the "expires" to the past date won't do anything, even to the other variables, and expire date does not exist no matter what. Also, cookies can't be manipulated in anyway by console.

Here's the code that sets the date to the past:
`document.cookie="a=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";`

And here's a editing part for comparison: 
`document.cookie="somevariable=0;expires="+expiretime+"; path=/";`

I don't know why it doesn't work, eventhough it seems that for other people it works. This happens on any platform, and the codes are run on the recent version of Chrome browser.

Comment: So, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie) didn't work for you?

Comment: @nicael Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Then I believe the problem is somewhere else in the code you haven't disclosed

Comment: @nicael That's weird since the console returns no error. Thanks alot for the help!