# Can not delete a specific cookie on Chrome by using document.cookie

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I want to delete a cookie named "_ga" which is a cookie of Google Analytics programatically.
* jQuery is not an option this time.

I understand we can delete a cookie by 1) setting a past expiration date 2) setting max-age=0. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie))

However, when I tried on Chrome, it doesn't delete the cookie.
To test its behavior, I set another cookie with the same name with null value.

```
document.cookie = "_ga=;";
```

I assume it will overwrite the existing cookie with the same name, but both cookies exist.

```
>document.cookie
<- "_ga=GA1.3.1150830279.1524399211; _ga="
```

Is it an expected behavior? If yes, how can I delete the cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Application` Tab inside chrome developer tools. Go to Cookies. Get the domain name for the `_ga` cookie. Now reset that with JS

```
document.cookie = "_ga=;domain=<domainName>"
```

When you set it without specifying the domain, it would be setting including the subdomain e.g. `www.domain.com` where as google would be setting it on `domain.com`