# How to delete a value from a existing cookie

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies

I have a add button which adds product id to the cart, which is handled by adding product id to the cookie separated by a pipe. Now on the cart page i have a remove button which should delete that particular product id from the cart which means the product id should be deleted from the cookie.

Ex: cookie value '22343|66562|88767'

when i cilck remove button on id 22343, the updated cookie value should be
'66562|88767'

How can i achieve this using javascript.

Comment: Hi look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

you can always update your cookie

```
document.cookie = "id=22343|66562|88767'"; // Create 'id' cookie
document.cookie = "id=66562|88767"; // Update the id cookie, i.e. overwrite
```

Further, if you want to delete, you expire the cookie

Read more at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    if (ca === null) return "";
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}


function eraseCookie(name) {
document.cookie = name + '=; Max-Age=-99999999;' }
```