# Why can I change a site's cookies in the dev tools, but not from the console?

Tags: browser, cookies

I've spent at least five hours trying to change the cookies of a website, which in my case was Facebook, through the console.

It appears that if I blank out `c_user` in the dev tools, I'm logged out. But when I tried to achieve the same thing in the console, nothing happens. I have tried the following two methods:

```
document.cookie[0]="c_user=0";
```

```
document.cookie.replace("c_user", "94029r23r");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing the JS correctly. What is important to understand is that `document.cookie` returns a string with all the cookie names and values. Let's look at what your code does to that string.

```
document.cookie[0]="c_user=0";
```

Taking element zero of a string returns the first character. In this case, you will get the first character of the name of the first cookie. Setting a character to a string is just nonsense, it does nothing and does not change the original string - `document.cookie`.

```
document.cookie.replace("c_user", "94029r23r");
```

I assume you are expecting this to replace the name of the cookie? Only problem is that the JS function `replace` does not change the input. It returns a copy with the replacements made on it. So again, you do not modify `document.cookie`.

For the correct way to do it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie). Or if you want something quick and dirty that removes the value, try this:

```
document.cookie = document.cookie.replace("[the session id]", "");
```

Comment: I just tried what you said at the bottom; it didn't log me out.

Comment: @AviG Did you do some debugging? Like check if `document.cookie` changed after you ran the code?

Comment: yes I did, and in the console it did, but not elsewhere and the page didn't log out

Comment: @AviG Huh, that is weird. If you reload the page, and then check the cookie, is it still changed or has it somehow reverted?