# Deleting cookies with javascript not showing expiration date

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to delete the cookies with javascript this way

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrCookies.length; i++){
                var key = arrCookies[i].split("=");
                document.cookie = key[0]+" =; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"; 
        }
```

but after execute this code, I called `document.cookie` and the reuslts doesn't show the expiration date that I just added  is this correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie)

Comment: My question is if I deleted the cookies as the original post , should I see this string `=; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC` when I call document.cookie

Comment: If you delete a cookie, the cookie should be gone right? Create `foo=bar`. `document.cookie` becomes `"foo=bar"`. Delete `foo`. `document.cookie` becomes `""`?