# Unable to delete cookies with my own function

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a function called deleteCookie to delete cookies. When I do some test cases, any of the test cases seems fine except for a cookie `name=John`. I have set this cookie two or three days ago but when I'm trying to delete it using my own function, `name=John` is still here. I'm wondering is there anything wrong with my function, or is there anything I don't know about when I'm deleting John

```
window.onload = () => {
    "use strict";
    let setCookie = (cname, cvalue, exdays, cpath) => {
        let d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = `${cname}=${cvalue}; expires=${d}; path=${cpath}`;
    }
    let getCookie = (cname) => {
        let ca = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split("; ");
        let name = cname + "=";
        for (let i =0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            while (ca[i][0] === " ") {
                ca[i] = ca[i].substring(1)
            }
            if (ca[i].indexOf(name) === 0) {
                return ca[i].substring(name.length, ca[i].length)
            }
        }
    }
    let deleteCookie = (cname, cpath) => {
        let c = getCookie(cname);
        if (c !== undefined && c !== null) {
            let d = new Date(0);
            d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = `${cname}=; expires=${d}; path=${cpath}`;
            return c;
        } else {
            return -1
        }
    }
    let changeCookie = (cname, cvalue, exdays, cpath) => {
        let c = getCookie(cname);
        if (c !== undefined && c !== null) {
            let d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = `${cname}=${cvalue}; expires=${exdays}; path=${cpath}`;
        } else {
            return -1
        }
    }
    setCookie("name", "Ben", 7, "/home/ubuntu/Documents/test/test.html");
    console.log(document.cookie)
    changeCookie("name", "Sam", 7, "/home/ubuntu/Documents/test/test.html");
    console.log(document.cookie);
    console.log(deleteCookie("name", "/home/ubuntu/Documents/test/test.html"));
    console.log(document.cookie);
    console.log(deleteCookie("name", "/home/ubuntu/Documents/test/test.html"));
    console.log(document.cookie);

}
```

Comment: Why all this code when [other approaches already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/how-to-delete-a-cookie)?

Comment: Agree with @tadman. You can use existing packages as well.

Comment: use the F12 developer tools of your browser and look at the cookie for differences that set it apart from other samples you have made. Could it have been set under a different cookie sub domain ?  Perhaps it is coming from somewhere else and by coincidence you used it as a sample case?

Comment: You're sure it's not `httpOnly`?